# How to change specific part of a file using java?

Tags: java, xml, io

I was writing a program that implements a dictionary.

Actually what I did is just to write a java applet to show the words which is defined in a .xml file. And I did that with the org.w3c.dom package.

Now, I want to add a new feature that users can modify a word in the dictionary in the the program then the modification will be saved to the original .xml file.

Here is my question: what should I do to save the changes? Note that users can only modify one word a time so I don't want to load the whole file and modify the certain part and re-write the whole file to the disk. Is there a novel way to do that?

Comment: You should definitely read something about [SAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html)

Answer (score 1):

An XML file is a sequential text file. This means that there is no formula or other convenient way to locate the n-th word in a dictionary stored in XML. Elements need to be written one after the other, character by character (and one character may or may not result in a byte). Thus, what is called a random update, is out.

Look at JAXB for a most convenient way to read and write XML, and invest some work so that a user cannot update in memory and terminate the program without saving.

Answer (score 0):

Reading and writing files in specific formats is a little bit trickier that what you portray.

Seen with "XML eyes" you are only changing a portion of the file - but to do that on the file level you need to `seek` to the position of change and write new bytes from there. The problem with that is that the content *after* that position won't adjust according to the new portion you write.

TL;DR - no - you need to read+write the complete XML file when making changes.